# SSRS BIDS 2008 Reporting Drop Down menu

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

Is it possible to add a drop down list in BIDS so that the user can select for example a Department Section from a long list of around 150 and then once selected drill through to a report containing data on that, i would simply produce a report with parameters however I do not want to specify over 150 records one by one!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

First you need to create a dataset with the data that you want to fill the drop down list, and then use it as the source for one of the report parameters. Look at the Report -> Parameters (if my memory serves) menu option.